# fast API add module (pandas) for the command uvicorn main:app --reload

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, fastapi, uvicorn

```js
import json
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.requests import Request
from typing import Dict
import sqlite3
from MockAPIAssureCare.csvToDB.csvToDB import csv_to_db_cursor
import os

app = FastAPI()


def create_json(cur: sqlite3.Cursor, query_without_where_clause: str, path_params: Dict) -> Dict:
    columns = []
    data = cur.execute(query_without_where_clause)
    for (column) in data.description:
        columns.append(column[0])

    where_clause = ""
    for key, value in path_params.items():
        if key not in columns:
            continue
        if where_clause == "" and value.lstrip('-').isdigit():
            where_clause += f"WHERE {key} = {value} "
        elif where_clause == "" and not value.lstrip('-').isdigit():
            where_clause += f"WHERE {key} = '{value}' "
        elif where_clause != "" and value.lstrip('-').isdigit():
            where_clause += f"AND {key} = {value} "
        else:
            where_clause += f"AND {key} = '{value}' "

    query = query_without_where_clause + where_clause
    data = cur.execute(query)
    dict_list = []
    for row in data:
        dict = {}
        for i in range(len(row)):
            # omit the index part
            if i == 0:
                continue
            dict[columns[i]] = row[i]
        dict_list.append(dict)
    return dict_list




@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}


@app.get("/hello")
async def hello():
    return {"message": "hello"}


def request_handler(cur, table):
    @app.get(f"/{table}")
    async def request(request: Request):
        path_param_key_value_pair = {}
        for key in request.query_params:
            path_param_key_value_pair[key] = request.query_params[key]

        return create_json(cur, f"Select * from {table} ", path_param_key_value_pair)


def main_wrapper():
    csv_file_list = list(map(lambda file: file[:file.index('.')], os.listdir('./csvFiles')))
    cur = csv_to_db_cursor(csv_file_list)
    for csv_file in csv_file_list:
        @app.get("/debug")
        async def debug():
            return "for loop has been called"
        request_handler(cur, csv_file)


main_wrapper()

# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_wrapper()
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)

# See PyCharm help at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/
```

I created the following python codes for python fast API. When I run the python script directly, everything works as I expected. However, when I run the code with the command
"uvicorn main:app --reload" on the terminal, I found the module not found error:

```
  File "..../root/csvToDB/csvToDB.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I think this messes up my deployment of the API server, and I wonder if there is a way to solve it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you also running the script directly in the same terminal and it works?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It only works when I click run button that IDE creates on the line (__name__ = "__main__")

Comment: So when you run either the script directly or uvicorn from the command line then it doesnt work. It sounds like your IDE is probably using a virtual enviroment for the packages. You probably want to also run a virtual enviroment on your terminal to contain all the packages you need.